# Query pandas DataFrame with user-defined rules

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operators

Python 3.8.1
pandas 0.25.3

I have two pandas DataFrames. One contains data that needs to be evaluated:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'TRANS_ID': ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'],
     'DATA_ONE': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pomegranate'],
     'DATA_TWO': [4, 5, 3, 5],
     'DATA_THREE': ['Mike', 'Bernadette', 'Laura', 'Mitchell'],
     'NEEDS_REVIEW': ''
     }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

print(df1)
```

The other contains user-defined rules:

```
import pandas as pd

f = {'RULE_CODE': ['aaa', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc'],
     'RULE_SEQ': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
     'CHECK_COL': ['DATA_ONE', 'DATA_TWO', 'DATA_TWO', 'DATA_TWO', 'DATA_THREE'],
     'CHECK_OPERATOR': ['equals', 'greater than', 'equals', 'in', 'contains'],
     'CHECK_VAL': ['Apple', 4, 5, '3, 5', 'Mi']
     }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = f)

print(df2)
```

How would I go about grouping the RULE_CODE and performing the `df2` rules on `df1`?

Desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

r = {'TRANS_ID': ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'],
     'DATA_ONE': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pomegranate'],
     'DATA_TWO': [4, 5, 3, 5],
     'DATA_THREE': ['Mike', 'Bernadette', 'Laura', 'Mitchell'],
     'NEEDS_REVIEW': ['', 'aaa, bbb', '', 'bbb, ccc']
     }
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data = r)

print(df3)
```

Would using an operator dictionary be practical?

```
import operator

ops = {'equals': operator.eq,
       'greater than': operator.gt
       'contains': operator.contains
       }
```

Thank you!

Comment: any particular reason this is in a dataframe, doesn’t seem like the _optimal_ data structure for this problem

Comment: A .csv with the data is generated every morning. What would be a better data structure?

Comment: that's a broad question to answer but I would think custom objects with name attributes which correspond to your comments would be better